# FileReader.OnLoad escalation in the code block

Tags: javascript, filereader, onload

I wrote 2 pieces of testing codes. They both triggered 'OK' message. Does it mean the OnLoad property (reference to a event handler upon data reading completed) gets escalated to the top of the code and gets called regardless its location?

1st piece

```
        var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];           
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {alert('ok');};
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
```

2nd piece

```
        var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
        reader.onload = function() {alert('ok');};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "escalated" (perhaps you mean [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)?), but what you're doing when you set a function to an onload property is adding an asynchronous event listener to it. So it will be called not *where* it is located in your program syntax (regardless of whether it's hoisted or not), but *when* the event is dispatched by the browser. It's not possible to know exactly when that will be ahead of time, but it will be at some point after your synchronous JavaScript code is finished executing and control of the main thread is returned to the browser.

Comment: sorry I meant hoisted